# Inserting a decimal from textbox to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, decimal, parameter-passing

I have an sql column which holds a decimal value..lets say latitude which comes from a textbox.

```
Latitude decimal(20,16),
```

Now i want to check if textbox is empty or contains non-decimal charaters,if yes..it should insert a default value like '0' or if everything is in place..just insert the decimal.

I have tried the below :

```
int latoutput;
string latinput = txtLatitude.Text;
bool latresult = int.TryParse(latinput, out latoutput);
if(latresult)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Latitude", Convert.ToDecimal(latinput));
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Latitude", null);
}
```

When the execute, even when the textbox contains valid decimal it goes on to the ELSE block and throws an exception that @Latitude was not provided.

Here there are two problems :

1. Why is it not taking the valid decimal as the input and gets in ELSE block?
2. I am not sure if decimal columns are nullable, if not what are my alternatives for default value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might take a look at this article too. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Be aware, you're getting `@Latitude was not provided` error because you should be passing `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `int.TryParse` instead of `decimal.TryParse`. If you enter anything with a decimal point, i.e. `123.45` then `int.TryParse` will fail. Update your code to use `decimal.TryParse`:

```
bool latresult = decimal.TryParse(latinput, out latoutput);
```

To answer your second question, decimal columns are nullable in a database if they are defined as nullable. I can't determine what you should be passing into your procedure without knowing what your schema looks like nor what your procedure looks like.

Comment: Answered all my questions.Thanks a ton